# Display all the same elements Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, web-scraping

I have a problem, i'm parsing IMDB web page using Simple HTML DOM Parser, and my code is the next one:

```
<?php
require('../simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'http://www.imdb.com/search/name?gender=female';
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach ($html->find('table.results tbody') as $div) {
    $extractname = $div->find('tr.detailed td.name a', 0);
    $extractimg = $div->find('tr.detailed td.image', 0);
    $name = $extractname->innertext;
    $img = $extractimg->innertext;
    echo $img, $name;
};
?>
```

This script returns me that:

[Link to image](http://oi59.tinypic.com/28ixdn6.jpg)

Well so my problem is that i don't know why my script only returns me one element, and not all the elements.

Thanks!

Comment: what result are you getting on `var_dump($html);`

Comment: make a screenshot and add that to the question instead of giving a link.

Comment: I can't put a screenshot I don't have 10+ rep. So I put a link to the screenshot.

Comment: Ronak Patel, the var_dump($html); returns me a lot of text! Like that: aylor Momsenobject(simple_html_dom)#1 (23) { ["root"]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#2 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(5) ["tag"]=> string(4) "root" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#4 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(6) ["tag"]=> string(7) "unknown" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(0) { } ["nodes"]=> array(0) { } ["parent"]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#2 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(5) ["tag"]=> string(4) "root" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(2) { [0]=> objec..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting one element **because `<tbody>` is only one** on that page.
You probably want to get result **for each tr** row.

> foreach ($html->find('table.results tbody tr') as $div) {}

Answer (score 0):

I usually use XPATH to do things like this, so forgive me if I am wrong.

To me it looks like find() gets an array, you should be looping over the $extractname as an array of elements just as you are doing with the $html find for tbody tags, and the same with $extractimg.

So to me a) you find all the tbody tags and loop them b) inside each tbody you are looking for the other elements which become their own arrays.